# How to fix ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS?

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a site on Django, but I got an error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I think that the matter is in the views.py file. Help figure it out.
P.S. already tried to delete cookie files, it didn't help(

```
from email import message
from wsgiref.util import request_uri
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.
def reg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        cpassword = request.POST['cpassword']
        if password == cpassword:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username):
                messages.info(request, 'Username taken')
                return redirect('registration')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
                user.save()
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Passwords not matching')
            return redirect('registration')
        return redirect('/')
    else:    
        return render(request, 'registration.html')

def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from your `return redirect('/')`. Redirect to one of the views written in your `urls.py` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Ok, but if I need to redirect to the home page, what should I specify? it`s urls.py in accounts ```from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('registration', views.reg, name='registration'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
]```

Comment: You should do it like for your other redirections : `return redirect('your_url_name')`. From your urls you don't seem to have a home page, you should create a url pattern linking to a view in order to redirect to it.

Comment: if @Balizok doesnt work try to add a backslash in the end like ```redirect('your_url_name/')```

Comment: But as far as I know, there is no name on the home page. Am I wrong?

Comment: In your urls it seems so...but you shouldn't be able to display a home page if it isn't in your url configuration. If you have a home page then it's defined somewhere, if not then you don't have a home page.

Comment: @Balizok sorry I sent another urls.py. This is the main urls.py ```from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: And in the `urls.py` in your main app (if your home page is defined there), you should have a home page, then link to its name.

Comment: So, I need to name home page?

Comment: Yes, if it doesn't already have a name.

Comment: If I change the name in the line ```path('', views.index, name='index')``` to 'home', I get an error that this page is not found. Here is the complete code of the urls.py file from the main app.
```from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('new_todo', views.newtodo, name='new_todo'),
    path('detail/<int:id>/', views.delete, name='delete')
]```

Comment: It already has a name which is `index`, in your redirection you just add to redirect to this name so `redirect('index')`

Comment: I add, but It doesn`t work( What files I need to show you? It`s views.py from accounts app. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GUoGzBf5Vl8tUxJbp-XiG8la1u-Bs0TT/view?usp=sharing  I use the link, because code is too long and I can`t send it in the comment

Comment: Does it still returns a `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` ? If so, it may be because you're calling your logout view from your home page which then creates a loop, maybe because of a missing verification or something like that

Comment: I change logout redirect, but it returns TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when I try to login into account

Comment: Try replacing your `return redirect('login')` with `return render(request, 'login.html')` in your login view when user authentication failed (not sure of me but that may be the cause)

Comment: This idea doesn`t work. Code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y1Y5Du8dGqAC-FkGiRh40Ufaw4LSNO0i/view?usp=sharing